# Helmcharts- how to access values nested inside a key that is a number?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to pull values out of a kubernetes helm chart values.yaml that has a number as one of the keys and I'm getting a `parse error unexpected ".1" in operand`. How can I access values that contain a number in its path?

Let's say my values.yaml looks like this:

```
global:
  foo:
    bar1: 1
  1:
    bar2: 2
```

Using helm charts, I can access `bar1` by typing: `{{ .Values.global.foo.bar1 }}`.

If I try to do the same with accessing `bar2` by typing: `{{ .Values.global.1.bar2 }}` I receive a parse error. It doesn't get better if I try to use brackets `{{ .Values.global[1].bar2 }}`, quotes `{{ .Values.global."1".bar2 }}`, or brackets and quotes: `{{ .Values.global["1"].bar2 }}`.

I know that helm charts utilize golang templates under the hood, is there some kind of template I could create to extract this information?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

The easy option is to just quote it in your values file so it's a string but:

```
{{ index .Values.globals 1 "bar2"}}
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I try that, the error is: `<index .Values.global 1 "bar2">: error calling index: value has type int; should be string`

Comment: Might be doomed then.